# how can we do webassembly fuzzing?

Tags: webassembly, fuzzing

i have a .wasm file and i want to do fuzzing on it. how can i do this? i am newbie in fuzzing and webassembly and i searched a lot to do this but i couldn't find any helpful thing. do you know any research in this field?

Comment: see: https://medium.com/wasmer/fuzz-testing-in-webassembly-vms-3a301f982e5a

Comment: see also: https://fuzzinglabs.com/fuzzing-javascript-wasm-dharma-chrome-v8/

Answer (score 0):

I've done some work on fuzzing WebAssembly with AFLplusplus here: https://github.com/KTH/slumps/tree/master/wasm-fuzzer

It uses a socket to forward fuzzed input to the instantiated WebAssembly module and then returns the coverage to AFL via the socket. It uses a standalone WebAssembly interpreter written in Scala, but should generally be fairly easy to set up.